# Provide local and online game-play without a lot of if-statements

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, network-programming

I'm building a simple game in Unity3D that can be played in offline as well as online mode. The game is quite simple (as a proof-of-concept). You have a sphere and can move it around. The online and offline versions are basically exactly the same, with the only difference that in the online version many players can control the sphere at the same time.

Right now I'm using a message passing method to send all movements to the server, which in return passes the message to all connected clients. However, this method wouldn't work, if I'm only running the game without a server, unless I have some sort of conditional statements for all possible interactions that check if I'm currently in local or online mode.

How can I design the code in a way that makes this sort of checking needless? I feel like it's quite the bad design otherwise.

My custom network manager looks like this:

```
public class CustomNetworkManager : NetworkManager {
    public override void OnStartClient(NetworkClient mClient) {
        base.OnStartClient(mClient); // base implementation is currently empty

        mClient.RegisterHandler ((short)CustomMessage.TRANSFORM, OnClientTransformMessage);
    }

    public override void OnStartServer() {
        base.OnStartServer();

        NetworkServer.RegisterHandler ((short)CustomMessage.TRANSFORM, OnServerTransformMessage);
    }

    private void OnServerTransformMessage(NetworkMessage netMsg) {
        var msg = netMsg.ReadMessage<CustomMessage.TransformationMessage> ();

        CustomMessage.TransformationMessage transformation = new CustomMessage.TransformationMessage ();
        transformation.translateVector = msg.translateVector;

        TranslateGameObject ("Sphere", msg.translateVector);

        NetworkServer.SendToAll ((short)CustomMessage.TRANSFORM, msg);
    }

    private void OnClientTransformMessage(NetworkMessage netMsg) {
        var msg = netMsg.ReadMessage<CustomMessage.TransformationMessage> ();

        TranslateGameObject ("Sphere", msg.translateVector);
    }

    private void TranslateGameObject(string objName, Vector3 translateVector) {
        GameObject obj = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag (objName);

        obj.transform.Translate (translateVector);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a local server when not connected to the network.  The local server will mimic the network server.

Comment: @jdweng Didn't occur to me, but yes, makes total sense!

Answer (score 0):

It just occurred to me, after [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng) comment. I can just run the game as a host, which is basically a server and a client in one!

Comment: This is the solution. Just be sure the code is independent of deployment. In the client this should imply only a change of IP address in a configuration file. You shouldn't have any line of code differentiating between online and offline. The only exception is if you have to differentiate between network conditions or network interfaces.

Comment: @rodolk Usually I would agree, but in my case it's a bit different. I do want to differentiate between online and offline, because if you're online, you can choose a specific room on the server to join.